# AWS RDS Postgres DB got hacked. How does it happen?

Tags: postgresql, security, amazon-rds

Recently, RDS postgres instance got hacked and new readme database was created with a message. While the DB is public facing and password may be guessed, how do hackers know the RDS connection string url. Also, there was a query executed to `DROP` database but the user or ip is logged as `UNKNOWN` on AWS logs, how come? While snapshot backups to restore is available, how to know what causes the breach.

Comment: DB public facing - that is your mistake. And likely a weak password on top of that. Do not try to figure out how they found your DB. There are millions way to do that, starting with someone "trusted" (other employee?) was part of that.

Comment: How did you configure your VPC, IAM and security groups? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.html

Comment: Can you share the actual log messages?

Comment: "password may be guessed".  What was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad practice to make a AWS database public. And if you do control inbound access with a security group that restricts access.

Regarding your question on how they guessed the endpoint, database hostnames are automatically generated like this:

database-1.ck9xkudewl4i.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

- database-1 is the part that you choose in the GUI
- ck9xkudewl4i is a random string added by AWS
- eu-west-1 is a finite set of regions

Your security model relies purely on the randomness of the second part (and a little on the first part, but this might be a fixed set of strings like db, database). I just generated two databases in succession and the two unique ID's I got were:

- database-1.ck9xkudewl4i.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
- database-2.ck9xkudewl4i.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com

This means that the second part is not even unique, it is probably connected to your AWS account or maybe even the underlying database instance that serves the requests!

I would advice to make the database non-public going forward. You can't rely on security through obscurity.

Comment: They don't even need to guess the hostname, just the IP address.

Comment: Exactly & you can scan the whole public IPv4 range in under 1 hour!